# Using multiple android spinner to get result simontaneously

Tags: java, android, spinner

This my code, I need to use both spinner result at the same time but this code return me only one spinner's selected value and for other spinner it return null. What do I need to change in the code so that I can use both spinner simontaneously.

```
statFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new function());
    statTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new function());



    }

public class function implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    String strFr, strTo;

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
         if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinFrom)
         {
             strFr = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

         }
         if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinTo)
         {
             strTo = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

         }
              Testing(strFr,strTo);
      }
```

Here I am getting only one spinner value and other is showing as null

Please help me !!!

Comment: Just save your spinner selection item in some other place and use that . When you try to get selected value from spinner it returns the current value. if nothing selected hen it returns 0. I think this is your problem

Comment: I am trying to get the value of both the spinner at the same time, extract the selected value as a string and then pass both the selected values of the spinners through a function.

testing(spinneroneselectedvalue , spinneroneselectedvalue )

Whenever there is a change in the selection of the spinner the value that I pass, must change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
strFr = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

with

```
strFr = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

& Similarly for strTo

Ideally it is a better idea to have separate variables pointing to separate views in your code.